# trying to sequence jquery ready event for an ng2 component in a .net mvc app

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm trying to sequence the jquery ready event for an ng2 component in a .net mvc app. I'm migrating some content from an mvc view into an ng2 component.

The existing mvc view had some logic applied to a particular html input in the jquery ready event. The new ng2 component has an html input with the same id but the jquery ready event logic isn't hooking into it.

Do I need to wireup jquery in a particular way for this scenario or when using ng2 in general?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve]. You can ask read more about [ask]

Comment: @0mpurdy - it's a pretty general question.  I need to be able to include a jQuery hook in an ng2 component.  the parent mvc view also needs a jquery hook.  I'm not sure if there's a way to include 1 jquery reference for both the view and the ng2 component. Since the mvc app uses javascript and the component uses typescript, I'm thinking that I'll probably need a 2 jquery references: 1 for the view and 1 for the component. But it seems like loading 2 jquery refs could potentially be problematic.